# For Loop prints after break

Tags: c++, loops, runtime-error

The even after entering 'q' during the first for loop(which should cause it to break. The for loop still prints out "Please enter up to one thousand values or enter 'Q' to exit: ".As I am not getting any sort of compiler error I can't seem to figure out what the issue could be.

```
unsigned int const size = 10;
StaticArray<int,size> arr;
int input;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter up to one thousand values or enter 'Q' to exit: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);
    if (input == 'Q' || input == 'q')
        break;
    else
        arr.Push(input);
}

//output array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.getSize(); i++)
{
    cout << i << ". " << arr.Top() << endl;
    arr.Pop();
}
```

Comment: When you do `cin >> input;` your `input` variable is an `int` so typing a letter like `Q` will cause an error on `std::cin`. After that error none of the `std::cin` function calls will work properly.

Comment: _`int input;`_ shouldn't this be `char input;`?

Answer (score 0):

When processing user input, you have to be a lot more careful about how you deal with the input, which could contain expected values as well as unexpected values. Here's something to get you started.

```
cin >> input;

// Check whether the number was successfully read.
if ( input.fail() )
{
   // The read could have failed due to reaching EOF
   // or by bad data. Check.
   if ( input.eof() )
   {
      // Do something sensible
   }
   else
   {
      // Clear the flags.
      input.clear();

      // Check whether the user entered Q or q
      char quit;
      input >> quit;
      if ( quit == `Q` || quit == `q` )
      {
         // Do the needful to quit.
      }
      else
      {
         // How do you want to handle the input if user entered 
         // something else...
      }
   }
}
else
{
   // The number was successfully read
   // Do the needful.
   // ...
}
```